# Problem trying to put a variable value into my Link to value for the URL

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error when trying to construct a URL in my link component:

> bundle.js:2567 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.

Here is what I have in my React component:

```
_renderSubNav() {
  const { dispatch } = this.props

  let userId = this.props.match.params.userId;
  console.log('userId is' + userId);

  return (
    <div className="">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol className="breadcrumb">
                <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to={`/users/${userId}`} className="nav-link">User</Link></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The console does log the id in chrome, so userId is not undefined it is e.g. 2.
How can I put the userId into the Link component?

Comment: The problem is in code that you didn't show us. Please show the code that calls this method

Comment: @DanielHilgarth if I remove the <li> tag everything renders fine.

Comment: Show your router config and what component is rendering against `/users`, show its code too

Comment: @Blankman: I think you need to create a minimal reproducible example, because the code you show is fine.

Comment: Did you import the `Link` component?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Here is what I am seeing: https://codesandbox.io/s/30ovxljqv1   So your saying it is my route setup issue?

Comment: I didn't say anything about the router and I don't think that this is the problem. That was someone else. The link you posted didn't contain any code related to your problem. Did you forgot to save?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth the codesandbox has the same error message as mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Important: `{Link}` and not `Link`. That's the error in your codesandbox and most likely also in your actual code.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like there's a different problem than the Link.

You're missing a return statement somewhere. From everything I remember about Link your syntax is fine and the error being thrown is not referencing the Link.